# App Store not allowing app downloads

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

The iOS App Store is a great place, normally, but recently I discovered that I'm not able to download apps due to some error.
The error is that whenever I want to download an app, I click GET, then it goes to the loading circle for a few seconds, then the button goes back to GET and my app doesn't download. Any solutions? I'm using an iPad Air 2 running the latest version of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me sometimes too, what I end up doing is killing the App Store application (going into the application switcher and the closing it) before trying to download again.
If it is still not working is usually reboot the iPad and try again.

Alternatively you can try to see if the app is in your bought history on the app and try to launch a download from there.